# Hibernate Bidirectional or two unidirectionals relations

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I have two entities Users and Groups , associated with Many-To-Many

a user belongs to many groups and he know them (navigabilite_1)
a group contain many users and he know them (navigabilite_2)

I want when I delete a user only user and the relation(in join table) get deleted not the group and the same for deleting groups should not affect user only the group and the relation

**What kind of association should I use Bidirectional or two unidirectional ,and where should I put the cascade on delete ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a bidirectional association, and you shouldn't use any cascade, since cascading would also delete the entity at the other side of the association.

Assuming `User.groups` is the owner side of the association, deleting a group would be done using

```
for (User user : group.getUsers()) {
    user.getGroups().remove(group);
}

// optional:
group.getUsers().clear();

session.delete(group);
```

And deleting a user would be done using

```
// optional:
for (Group group : user.getGroups()) {
    group.getUsers().remove(user);
}

user.getGroups().clear();

session.delete(user);
```

Comment: so there is no way to make it automatically ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such possibility, no. Unless you use cascade options in the database itself.

Comment: I should use just one loop+remove or clear not the both in the sametime ?